# Properties File. Parse Out Certain Text. (String)

Tags: java, parsing

In my properties file that I have for a mod I'm making for Minecraft I will need to have my properties file recognized certain words as being variables. These words will be contained like so: {variable name}

Here is an example of what might need to be parsed:

```
command01 = /ban {user} g {reason}  //This is read into the variable command1 only taking the things after the equals sign
```

{user} would be defined in an input box in the GUI. {reason} would also be as well.

{User} would equal the variable user which would be a String
{Reason} would equal the variable input1 which would be a String as well

Lets say the variable user holds the string "Fogest" and the input1 variable holds the string "He did xyz wrong".

I essentially need to retrieve that value from the GUI which is already done, and then replace {User} and {Reason} with what those variables are equal to in the GUI.

After all my rambling the question is how would I go about parsing the string command1 to find placeholders such as {user} and {reason} and replace them with what the corresponding variable holds.

I hope this isn't to confusing. If it just mention it in the comments and I will try and rephrase it.

Comment: Something like `command01 = command01.replaceAll("{user}", value)`, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you question boils down to is some kind of string substitution.  I think what you're looking for is something like this

```
String someString = "We went to the {location}.";
System.out.println(someString.replace("{location}", "store"));
```

Running this code produces

```
We went to the store.
```

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I wanted! I didn't expect it to be so simple for some reason :). Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking on the Java Docs at the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) file and I'm confused as to what the replace does in comparison to replaceALL. What is the difference or when would I want to use replaceALL?

Comment: Also I want to only do this if it contains a part of this. So that means I need some check first to see if it contains that. And if it does then it should replace it. What method do I use for this?

Comment: If I'm understanding your last comment/question right, if you call the replace and the "{location}" is not there, then it won't affect the string at all.

Comment: As to the replaceAll, if you look at the arguments that it takes, the replaceAll takes a regular expression as the first argument, instead of just a string match/replace.  If you're more interested in using that, then you can look up the java Pattern class.